# Access JSON values in PHP (one part is working, other one not)

Tags: php, json

I have this JSON:

```
[
{
    "Ticket": {
        "TicketNo": 1920,
        "Creation": "21.03.2016 05:45:00",
        "FailureDescription": "Error 46",
    },
    "Measures": [
        {
            "StartTime": "2017-03-17T05:45:00",
            "Description": "Long description",
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Ticket": {
        "TicketNo": 1005,
...
```

and here is the code I use to display data:

```
$file = file_get_contents($remote_url, false, $context);
$myData = json_decode($file);

foreach($myData as $myItem) {
   echo "<tr><td>$myItem->TicketNo</td><td>CLOSED</td><td>$myItem->Creation</td><td>$myItem->FailureDescription</td></tr>";
   echo "<tr><th>Start</th><th>Measure</th></tr>";

   foreach ($myItem->Measures as $wm) {
      echo "<tr><td>$wm->StartTime</td><td>$wm->Description</td></tr>";
   }
}
```

**Problem is, that the 'Ticket' part is not showing at all, but the 'Measures' part is working well. I think it's because of the missing [ ] after 'Ticket'**, but I'm desperate to make it work.

JSON is valid and var_dump($myData) returns all of the data. I've tried to decode the JSON with 'json_decode($file, true)' to get an array and use $mydata['Ticket']['TicketNo'] but it didn't work either. I've tried '$myData->Ticket' in the first foreach with no effect. I've also read all the offered similar questions here in SO, but I didn't find a solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two errors here.

Firstly, you need to read the structure of the JSON carefully to see what to access. The JSON has:

- An array `[`, which you are looping with `foreach($myData as $myItem) {`
- Each item in that array, has two keys: "Ticket" and "Measures"; access them as `$myItem->Ticket` and `$myItem->Measures`
- Each "Ticket" has the keys "TicketNo", "Creation", and "FailureDescription". Those are not keys of `$myItem`, they are sub-keys of `$myItem->Ticket`; in other words, `$myItem->Ticket->TicketNo`, `$myItem->Ticket->Creation`, and `$myItem->Ticket->FailureDescription`

Your second problem is that when you write `$myItem->Ticket->TicketNo` inside a double-quoted string, like `"hello $myItem->Ticket->TicketNo world"`, PHP thinks you want the variable `$myItem->Ticket` followed by the literal text `"->TicketNo world"`. To fix that, put the variable part in curly braces: `"hello {$myItem->Ticket->TicketNo} world"`.

So the `echo` line should be:

```php
echo "<tr><td>{$myItem->Ticket->TicketNo}</td><td>CLOSED</td><td>{$myItem->Ticket->Creation}</td><td>{$myItem->Ticket->FailureDescription}</td></tr>";
```

Comment: For Godsake, I spent a whole day with this. I tried $myItem->Ticket-TicketNo before, but never used curly braces. Thank you, you've saved me!